# Permission denied when using TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging, flask

I made a REST API using Flask-RESTFUL for this one and I need to generate log files for this

I am getting an error when I have to run my API again. this occurs when it is logging on to the file.

```
 PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
```

To avoid this error, I had to delete the file but the same error occurS when another computer tries to access the API.

I have my config.py code initializing the app configuration of my logging module.

```
        import os
        from datetime import date
        import logging
        import logging.handlers as handlers

        class BaseConfig(object):
            DEBUG = False
            TESTING = False
            LOGGING_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
            #LOGGING_LOCATION = 'logs/bookshelf.log'


        class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
            DEBUG = True
            TESTING = True



        class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
            DEBUG = False
            TESTING = True

        class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
            DEBUG = False
            TESTING = False



        config = {
            "development": "config.DevelopmentConfig",
            "testing": "config.TestingConfig",
            "default": "config.DevelopmentConfig",
            "production": "config.ProductionConfig"
        }


        def configure_app(app):

            #ENVRIONMENT CONFIGURATION
            config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIGURATION', 'default')
            #config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIGURATION', 'production') #UNCOMMENT IF PROD
            app.config.from_object(config[config_name]) # object-based default configuration
            #handler = logging.FileHandler(app.config['LOGGING_LOCATION'])
            handler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/'+str(date.today())+'-mipay-error.log', when='M', interval=1)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(app.config['LOGGING_FORMAT'])
            #handler.setLevel(app.config['LOGGING_LEVEL'])
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            app.logger.addHandler(handler)
            #LOGGING CONFIGURATION
```

I have read that it is required to close the file but I do not know when and how to close the log file.

Comment: I was facing similar issue. Changing value of `debug` to `False` worked for me.

Comment: @Sociopath mine doesnt write to the log file anymore

Comment: @Sociopath had to include this line. app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)